# How can I disable the html minification in the htmlwebpackplugin config?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am developing a react app I tried to change the configs into minify: false but it didn't work?
any suggestions on How to fix this?
This is a snap of the Error:
[The error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38WVe.png)

Answer (score -1):

Add webpack.config.js

```
optimization: {
    minimize: false,
    minimizer: [
        minify: false
    ],
}
```

Comment: in the plugin folder?